# How to modify Double value in android

Tags: java, double

Suppose, I have a double value.

```
double dble = 5.91742691
```

Now can I get that value with two digits after the point. I mean to say,can I get 5.91 from there programmatically?

One more, suppose,  I want to get an integer from a double value if the double value is **X.9XXXXX**. Here I mean to say, I want to compare the **AFTER-POINT value**. For your understanding here **dble**'s **AFTER-POINT** value is *91742691*. How can I do that?

Comment: Please limit your questions to one per post.

Comment: You can't. Doubles don't have decimal places. They have binary places, and these are incommensurable with decimal places. If you want decimal places you have to use a decimal radix.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to truncate a double to 2 decimal places, do

```
double twoDecDbl = (int)(dble * 100) / 100.0; // 5.91
```

or

```
double twoDecDbl = Math.floor(dble * 100) / 100; // 5.91
```

However, if you want to get the numbers after the decimal place as an integer (which I don't know why you would want to do this), then do

```
long decimals = Long.parseLong(("" + dble).split("\\.")[1]); // 91742691
```

**Note**: The maximum value of an `int` is 2,147,483,647 (10 digits there), but a double can hold 16 digits after the decimal point, so a `long` must be used in order to stay safe (can have 19 digits). Alternatively, you can just keep it as a `String` by removing the wrapping parse.

Comment: I've tested all 3 of these. They all work exactly as expected with any value for `dble` (unless of course it is within 2 digits of overflowing a double, which is quite unlikely).

Comment: Ok, how can I get the BEFORE-POINT VALUE? I mean to say, how can I get 5 from 5.91742691?

Comment: UPDATE: I now understand what you meant by AFTER-POINT. It is fixed now.

Comment: @MuhammadJobayer just do `(int)dble` to get the numbers before the point as an integer. After-point was trickier.

Comment: I got. Thanks for help.

Comment: Hey, I fixed my answer for the after-point number. I forgot that the `.` is a special character in regex, so it needs escaping.

Comment: I fixed my answer again so that `int` can't overflow. Read my note.

Comment: Thanks for doing everything

Answer (score -1):

For #1 Try it

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
String s = formatter.format(dble);
double num = Double.valueOf(s);
```

or

```
dble = Math.floor(dble * 100) / 100;
```

For #2 Try it

```
double num = dble - (int)dble;
```

In case `Integer.MIN_VALUE < dble < Integer.MAX_VALUE`

Comment: Your #2 doesn't work. It gives `0.91742691`

Comment: You can convert it to string then remove `0.` at the begining.

Comment: If `number1 = 1.92` and `number2 = 2.1111`, which AFTER-POINT value is greatter?

Comment: It depends, is that value of 1.92 actually 1.92000? Because in that case then 92000 is greater than 1111. Otherwise, 1111 is greater than 92.

Comment: Sorry, your first one worked. But second one was wrong.